# Can I use the YYYYMMDD-token *and* have the most recent logfile without the "_YYYYMMDD"-appendix?

Tags: wrapper, tanuki

my current logging configuration looks like this:

```
wrapper.logfile=/something/logs/wrapper.YYYYMMDD.log
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0
wrapper.logfile.rollmode=DATE
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=27
```

With this I´m producing logs like this:

```
wrapper.20231204.log
wrapper.20231205.log
wrapper.20231206.log
```

Now I would **really** like the most current log file to have the name wrapper.log, without the YYYYMMDD appendix.

I´ve read the [documentation](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-logfile.html#Token). With the *ROLLNUM* token this is possible. But it seems not possible with the *YYYYMMDD* token.

Am I overseeing something?

Thanks a lot

Lars

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was `rollmode=DATE`.

I changed it to `rollmode=WRAPPER`. This, in connection with the `wrapper.logfile=/something/logs/wrapper.YYYYMMDD.log` results in logs like these:

```
wrapper.20231204.log
wrapper.20231205.log
wrapper.20231206.log
wrapper.log
```